# How do I address someone with a term that is the opposite of Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, terminology

I am writing a wedding ceremony for two folks who are huge Star Wars fans.  Most of the ceremony is typical (with the exception of "I do" or do not.  There is no try.) but, at the end, before I announce them with their last name I want to say something like; "Ladies and gentleman, boys and girls, Jedi and Dark Jedi -- for the first time ever...Mr. and Mrs.....)

**Would that be correct or would there be a better way to characterize the "anti" (again, forgive me) Jedi?  I want to get this right for them.**

Comment: Probably 'Jedi & Sith' would work better... But I have a feeling this will be closed as Off-Topic.

Comment: No, matter!  You helped!  I will use it...

Comment: No problem; you might want to contact the [Universal Life Church](http://ulc.org), too -- as I recall, they have a Jedi program, and Wedding Ceremonies.. Dunno that they have a Wedding FOR Jedi.. but they might.

Comment: Incidentally, George Takei posted [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66475677/Jedi%20Wedding.jpg) a little while ago.

Comment: The wedding is this afternoon! LOL  I have had it written for weeks but just started getting nervous at the rehearsal last night about the "dark Jedi" reference and thought -- I better find someone who KNOWS.  So, your suggestion will be in a wedding at 5:00 tonight!  Again, I thank you.  I feel much more comfortable now! (And all my weddings are surprises to the bride and groom...but they are playing the "Throne THeme" as their recessional so I know it will go over well!  Thank you again!

Comment: "Jedi and Jar-Jars". \*me ducks and runs\*

Comment: @KHW - first, make that an answer. Second, it's so NOT off-topic... it's a question about a fictional world, with a well defined answer.

Comment: Jocelyn - also, if you want other, more subjective advice on this, you're welcome to participate in the SFF.SE chat room once you have enough reputation points. People would be delighted to advise.

Comment: Thank you!  I would love it.  But, about that reputation thing, do I have to start cleaning graffiti off of bathroom walls? I should have listened to my mother when she started that "reputation" speech!  Sincerely, though, it would be so useful for me as I customize all my weddings and this isn't the first SF reference (nor will it be the last!) I appreciate ALL the help.  You made my day (and a VERY big day for two other people!).

Comment: @JocelynAnnGreenleaf - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 6):

[Converted from a comment]
I believe the phrase that would work better would work better would be 'Jedi and [Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith).'

Incidentally, [Dark Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi) *do* exist in canon, but the Sith are what most people know, as they are the enemies shown in the movies.

You may also find some useful information from the [Universal Life Church](http://ulc.org); they have a Jedi program, as I recall, as well as books of wedding ceremonies; I don't know that they have a Jedi Wedding Ceremony, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: I'd be very careful here. "Sith" is an invention of the new trilogy. I'd wager there is a chance of a "huge Star Wars fan" being offended by having their "most important day" diminished by the prequels, as many fans reject the "new era". In ANH Vader was called "a master of evil" by his old master Obi-Wan. There were no siths around in ANH.

Comment: The first mention of the Sith was actually in the novelization of Episode IV, and it was widely used in the expanded universe long before the new trilogy as well. If they are Star Wars "movies only" fans, then yes, it _may_ cause a problem, but if they are truly "huge fans", I'd wager they also are fans of the expanded universe, which includes quite a lot of Sith references and characters.

Comment: @Dungarth: You are correct, I was [wrong](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7536/2565). However, the film-argument still applies, making "Sith" a dangerous choice.

Comment: @bitmask - totally! There _are_, after all, "movies only" Star Wars fan out there. They're a quite vocal minority, too. Since it seems the ceremony is already done by now, I'm really curious as to how it went ^_^

Comment: Unless the wedding attendees are all hard-core SW fans, I'd guess that the term Sith is going to be more familiar to everyone there. Dark Jedi makes sense, of course, but since nearly everyone has seen the latest movies - unless you're living under a rock - they're going to know what a Sith is.

Answer (score 2):

Jedi and Sith would work if the bride/groom are fans of prequel trilogy and/or Expanded Universe.  Otherwise I'd use "Jedi's and Darths".

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Jedi and Dark Lords.  This term was used in the Rise of Darth Vader, and seems to flow pretty good when spoken.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i would use Padawan. they are not yet jedi.