# When was current meaning of "Sith" established?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

In Timothy Zahn [Thrawn trilogy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Thrawn_Trilogy), all force-sensitive characters who draw from the dark side of the Force are referred to as "Dark Jedi". That includes Vader and Palpatine, who we would call "Sith" today.

It's clear that in early 1990s, there were no "Sith order", "Sith religion" or "Sith race" yet. The word "Sith" existed, first being used in novelization of A New Hope ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sith#Origin_of_the_word_Sith)), but it referred exclusively to Darth Vader then. It's also confirmed by Wookieepedia, which says that "the term »Sith« would not be properly defined for another few years" ([Source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi/Legends#Behind_the_scenes)).

When was current meaning of "Sith" established? What is the first work that defined our current understanding?

Comment: Good question. My first exposure to the word was on the front of a commenerative magazine celebrating the release of the "special" editions in the cinema. The cover was a head shot of DV with the headline "The Dark Lord of the Sith". I had no idea what it meant at the time.

Comment: This is **not** duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7529/57116 . The other question asks for first mention of "Sith" in Star Wars universe; this question acknowledges first mention occurred early, but builds on well-cited premise that meaning of word was not established in early 1990s and asks specifically when the word got meaning it has now and when this meaning became common knowledge among Star Wars fans.

Answer (score 3):

As early as 1973:

Until the recent GREAT REBELLION,
the JEDI BENDU were the most
feared warriors in the universe.
For one hundred thousand years,
generations of JEDI perfected their
art as the personal bodyguards of
the emperor. They were the chief
architects of the invincible
IMPERIAL SPACE FORCE which expanded
the EMPIRE across the galaxy,
from the celestial equator
to the farthest reaches of the GREAT RIFT.

Now these legendary warriors are
all but extinct. One by one they have
been hunted down and destroyed as
enemies of the NEW EMPIRE by a ferocious
and sinister rival warrior sect,
THE KNIGHTS OF SITH.

-- https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars:_Rough_Draft

Comment: I can't accept this answer, as multiple sources indicate that by early 1990s, it was not a common knowledge what "Sith" are. It could help if you could provide when this early draft was released to the public, how it happened that original meaning was lost or - the real point of the question - how and when it was re-introduced.

Comment: Well, I didn't post the source as I wasn't 100% sure of it's legitimacy and went to the wiki first. That said, there is an alleged original draft over here on this site:

http://maddogmovies.com/almost/scripts/starwars_rough5-74.pdf

Also, I'm not sure you can say "when did it decide our current understanding" as, like everything else, including Luke's parentage, that all "evolved" over time. :)

Edited because I hit the enter key too soon...

Answer (score 2):

The notion of the Sith, as an order of evil Force users, was introduced in *The Phantom Menace*.  The name "Sith" is much older, appearing in early screenplays for *The Star Wars* and first published in the Alan-Dean-Foster-ghostwritten *Star Wars* novelization.  However, in those early appearances, "Lord of the Sith" was an unexplained title.  (In fact, the novelization suggests that Darth Vader's appearance may actually be common to all Sith lords.)  There was nothing concrete that indicated that there was a Sith order, or that that order necessarily had anything to do with the Force

Prior to *The Phantom Menace*, as noted in the question, villains attuned to the Dark Side of the Force were frequently described as "dark Jedi," especially in the works of Timothy Zahn, which were the most prominent expanded universe works in the run-up to the release of the first prequel.*

*The Phantom Menace* also introduced (or at least formalized) the principle that the Sith lords were titled "Darth."  This was a cause of some discussion and debate among fans when the character list for the movie was released to the press, because in *A New Hope* Obi-Wan appears to treat "Darth" as a part of his former student's proper name:

> **OBI-WAN:**  You can't win, Darth.  If you strike me down, I shall become more powerful than you can possibly imagine.

There was also some discussion, after *Episode I* hit theaters, of whether a "Sith" and a "dark Jedi" were exactly the same thing.  The argument in favor of this proposition was based largely on Qui-Gon's lines from the film.  Shortly after the confrontation with Darth Maul:

> **OBI-WAN:**  What was it?
>   **QUI-GON:**  I'm not sure... but he was well trained in the Jedi arts.  My guess is he was after the Queen....

Then more prominently later, before the Jedi council:

> **QUI-GON:**  He was trained in the Jedi arts.  My only conclusion can be that it was a Sith Lord.
>   **KI-ADI:**  Impossible!  The Sith have been extinct for a millennium.
>   **MACE WINDU:**  I do not believe the Sith could have returned without us knowing.

This suggests that dark Force users (or at least those whose particular skill set—including lightsaber use—closely matches that of the Jedi) are automatically considered Sith.  Therefore, it was argued by a number of fans that "dark Jedi" and "Sith" were synonyms.  In fact, it turned out that the canonical solution (at least for the prequel trilogy) was to remove the notion of "dark Jedi" from the canon, with the light-aligned Jedi order being the only "Jedi" *sensu stricto*.

The "Sith race," on the other hand, was entirely a product of expanded universe materials—to the extent that one could watch the movies and essentially never encounter the notion.  The supposed Sith home planet was introduced in the 1994 *Tales of the Jedi:  Dark Lords of the Sith* comic book series, which turned out to be inconsistent with many subsequent works.  However, the idea of the Sith having originally been a single race has continued along since in a certain train of expanded universe works of dubious canonicity.

*It is possible that the notion of a Sith as an evil order was first introduced in some lesser-known expanded universe material that I am not familiar with.  However, it is important to keep in mind that in between the releases of *Return of the Jedi* and *The Phantom Menace*, a prodigious number of expanded universe works were released—many of which made only cursory attempts to be consistent with the original three films, and practically no attempt to be consistent with one-another.  No one is likely to treat revelations from the Saturday-morning *[Ewoks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewoks_(TV_series))* cartoon as having any canonical standing, and many of the novels written in this period were thought of the same way.  As another example, *[The Courtship of Princess Leia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Courtship_of_Princess_Leia)*, although a bestseller, was frequently derided for a treatment of Force users utterly at odds with what had been described in the original films and in Zahn's novels.  In any case, George Lucas made it clear that, as he was preparing the prequel trilogy, he was essentially not paying any attention to any facts establish in the various expanded universe sources—so the Sith being an evil order was a new invention (or perhaps something he had long had in mind, however had not included in the original films) for *The Phantom Menace*.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is pretty much wrong. As @EDenall's answer indicated, the Sith as evil counterparts of the Jedi existed in the earliest concepts. In addition, even the novelisation of the original Star Wars by Alan Dean Foster named Darth Vader as Dark Lord of the Sith.

Comment: @Marakai It was just a word in the original *Star Wars* novelization.  There was nothing concrete that indicated that there was a Sith order, or that that order necessarily had anything to do with the Force.

Comment: Agreed and I saw you incorporated it into your answer. In context with the previous answer it does show that the concept existed, at least in Lucas' head and some of his jottings.

Comment: @Buzz I think you are right by placing it around Phantom Menace time. I was but a child then, but I definitely knew what "Sith" are, that Vader and Emperor are Sith, that Sith have red lightsabers and "Darth" is a title that Sith have. I assumed that was always a case, but Thrawn trilogy and subsequent research showed that "Sith" as a concept was solidified a long time after original trilogy.